# PHP Convert string (1234) to integer

Tags: php, string

So in php `$a = 1234;` and `$a = (1234);` are both valid integers, 1234.

I have a situation with some third party code where I have `$a = "(1234)";` (ie, a string)

The normal converting string to int don't work (because of the brackets)

```php
<?php
$b = (int) $a; // 0
$b = intval($a); // 0
```

I could do something like

```
preg_match('/^\(([\d]+)\)$/', $a, $m);
$b = $m[1];
```

Just wondering if there there some clever way of converting $a back into an integer that I have missed?

Comment: (1234) in accounting means a -1234, so don't be too quick to strip those brackets.

Comment: @Augwa accounting is strange. Why use 2 extra characters when you could use 1?  (an all other fields would understand that one too)

Comment: The silly thing to do would be `eval("\$b = $a");` and then check `$b` . I only say this because `$a = (1234)` is not actually a valid integer in PHP, it's a valid *expression* which evaluates to an integer. By expression I mean the contents of the parenthesis are first evaluated and the result is stored in `$a`.

Comment: @apokryfos Yes, you are/were right. I misread question.

Answer (score 3):

The one more option can be

```
$str = "(1234)";

$int = (int) trim($str, '()');
```

Answer (score 0):

This will make sure that if it has `()` that it makes it a negative number.

```
$a = '1234';

if (0 !== preg_match('/^\((\d+\))$/', $a, $matches)) {
    $b = (int)-$matches[1];
} else {
    $b = (int)$a;
}
```